# Huge time to first byte on live site

Tags: php, performance, apache

I have problems with loading my site. 
Time to first byte varies from 0,5 to even 10s. I can't find what may cause that lag in back-end processing.

**My site** : [www.mm.bartoszwasz.pl](https://www.mm.bartoszwas.pl)

**Test with GMetrix** https://gtmetrix.com/reports/mm.bartoszwas.pl/SdPhlpjs
[image: load time]

**What i already did:**

1. Hosting response test - `ping www.mm.bartoszwas.pl` gave me result of 15ms
2. Putting small php file into my child-theme to check access time (15ms)
   https://mm.bartoszwas.pl/wp-content/themes/storefront-child/test.php
3. Links changed to **HTTPS** from normal **HTTP** - to avoid redirects.
4. Links in **wp-config** and **database** updated to *HTTPS*
5. Disabled plugins

Is anything else i can try?

Comment: I can't diagnose, because from here (in U.S.) it is loading almost instantly each of 20 times I tried.

Comment: Thank's for testing. Good to hear you don't have any problems, that means that the problem doesn't occur that often. But still i have to lower this TTFB time. Even 2s is huge..

Answer (score 0):

To check on your own system, use the Developer Tools (usually F12) and the Network tab. That will tell you which request is taking too much time.

Comment: I specified that **(TTFB)** is sometimes long, then site is loaded almost instantly. DevTools can't help me with this case, it shows only how long it took this time to load.